# Select min value with specific where filters MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, where-clause, min

I have a little trouble with my subquery. I try to only take the nearest event in a table with a min value, but I need it to be confirmed (confirmed = 1 and cancelled = 0)

There's my table :

```
uid | location | date         | open    | close  | confirmed | 
1   |  aaa     |  2015-05-11  |  12:00  |  14:30 |  1        |
2   |  aaa     |  2015-05-12  |  15:00  |  22:30 |  0        |
3   |  aaa     |  2015-05-15  |  11:00  |  18:30 |  0        |
4   |  aaa     |  2015-05-16  |  09:00  |  16:00 |  1        |
```

And there is my query : (`$now` is a php date of current hour (H:i) and `$today` a php date in format Y-m-d)

```
SELECT location, MIN(date)
FROM  table
WHERE confirmed = 1
AND IF (
    (close > '$now' AND date = '$today') OR (date> '$today'), 1, 0
)
GROUP By location
```

So in the test format, we are May 11 at 17:00. The first one shouldn't be selected because it happened in the past (this morning) and the second one should not be selected too because i put confirmed to 0

The expected result is

```
aaa  | 2015-05-16
```

because its the nearest with the confirm to true,

but it always returns me

```
aaa  | 2015-05-12
```

It doesn't care about the where statement of confirmed = 1, but it cares about the if (close > '$now' AND date = '$today') OR (date> '$today'), 1, 0 because it returns me the second one.

Can someone provide me some help please?

P.S.: It's all in MySQL

Thank you.

-- Carlos

**EDIT :::**

I just tried to add some value in the select (SELECT *, MIN(date))

and it returns me asymetric data ???

I got

```
| 4  | aaa  | 2015-05-16 | 09:00 | 16:00 | 1 | 2015-05-12
```

So the first date is the good one and the second one (with the min()) isn't the good one.

**LAST EDIT :::**

AS suggested spencer7593 (thanks to him/her), i just removed the min(date) and it automatically returns me the data I want, the good sql is :

```
SELECT *
FROM  table
WHERE confirmed = 1
AND IF (
    (close > '$now' AND date = '$today') OR (date> '$today'), 1, 0
)
GROUP By location
```

Comment: To be clear. You are trying to find the location from the first confirmed record after the supplied date and time?

Comment: Everything closes before midnight?

Comment: Yes everything close before midnight and open after 2 am. I want the futur event for every locations (with the group by) my database has a lot of locations and events for all of them. I need the next confirmed one

Comment: EDIT::: remove the aggregate function (`MIN`) and the `GROUP BY` clause, as a test, as I recommended in my answer. Other RDBMS would throw an error with the statement you show in the EDIT. ("non aggregate in select list not in group by"). A non-standard MySQL extension allows for this behavior, the "asymetric data" being returned, because the values returned for the non-aggregate columns are not deterministic. MySQL is free to return the values of the non-aggregate columns from *any* row that satisfies the predicates.

Comment: @spencer7593 - WOW it actually works!! I remove the min(date) but not the group by (as i need it for more location) and it gives me the right answer. Thank you ! (I can't select your answer, because it's a comment in my post)

Comment: @Carlos: **No**. The query in the last edit is *not* guaranteed to work. That is returning values from columns from indeterminate rows for each location. I suggested removing the **aggregate** and the **group by** as a **test** to see the actual rows that were satisfying the predicates in the WHERE clause. I suspect that the `GROUP BY` is masking the real problem, some anomaly in the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
SELECT location, MIN(date)
FROM  table
WHERE confirmed = 1
AND ((close > '$now' AND date = '$today') OR (date> '$today'))
GROUP By location
```

Maybe the If statement is making the behavior wrong.

Comment: I already tried to remove it. It doesn't change anything. It doesn't listen. My if statement is valid.

Comment: I see whats the problem, try ussing the having statement. This is the where for the group by.

Comment: SELECT location, MIN(date)
FROM  table
GROUP By location HAVING confirmed = 1
AND ((close > '$now' AND date = '$today') OR (date> '$today'))

Answer (score 0):

Given the example data, it certainly doesn't look like the date value of `2015-05-12` should be returned.

I'm questioning what the **datatypes** of the columns are, the **`confirmed`** column in particular. If that column is **`CHAR`** or **`VARCHAR`**, perhaps the comparison is being done as character, rather than numeric, and there's some hidden characters that's making it unequal.

If that's the case, and it's trailing characters in the column value, you can try casting `confirmed` to numeric by adding a zero to it in the statement, e.g.

```
WHERE confirmed+0 = 1
```

That expression `confirmed+0` will be evaluated in numeric context.

I'm also suspicious of the datatypes of the `date` and `close` columns, if those are also VARCHAR or CHAR... though that wouldn't explain why the predicate on `confirmed` is being ignored.

We're just guessing, there's not enough information to really tell what's happening.

For debugging this type of issue, `echo` or `vardump` the SQL text before it's sent to the database, so you can see what's actually being sent.

```
  $sql = "SELECT ....   " . $var . " ... ORDER BY 1";
  echo $sql;  # for debugging

  $dbh->query($sql);
```

I'd take that SQL text thats emitted, and test in another client. I'd try removing the `MIN` aggregate function and the `GROUP BY`, and return all of the relevant columns from the rows, to see the actual rows that are being grouped.

Comment: confirmed is a tinyint (0 or 1 boolean) and date, open and close are varchar

Comment: @Carlos2W: Are you positive that there isn't a row with location='aaa', date(character)='2015-05-12' and confirmed=1 ? I'd run a query against the table without the aggregation (remove the `GROUP BY` and the aggregate function). (The normative pattern is to use `DATE` datatype for date values, and `TIME` datatype for time values, rather than VARCHAR... but that doesn't explain the behavior you're seeing with the predicate on the `confirmed` column.)

Comment: Yes, because I just created a new table with only these four row to test and it gives me the same result.

Comment: Can you create a SQLFiddle that replicates this behavior? Very odd. Are you sure you're running the query against the new table you created for a test? Are any UPDATE or DELETE changes you made to any rows not yet committed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to find the location from the first confirmed record after the supplied date and time.

```
SELECT `location`, `date`
FROM `table`
WHERE `confirmed` = 1 
   AND (`date` > '$today'
         OR (`date` = '$today' AND `close` > '$now')
       )
ORDER BY `date`, `close`
LIMIT 1
;
```

Comment: No, because there's other locations, i want a list of location with their nearest record (with the group by) but its true it may confuse in my example because it has only one location